# JClouds-Chef not bootstrapping & configuring VM

Tags: java, chef-infra, jclouds

I am trying to get the following [JClouds-Chef](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/) code (v1.7.3) to bootstrap Chef Client on a brand new Linux VM and then execute a run list to actually configure that VM with an app stack (`typical_app`):

```
public class ChefPlugin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChefPlugin.provision();
        System.out.println("And done!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static provision() {
        String vmIp = "myapp01";
        String vmSshUsername = "myadmin";
        String vmSshPassword = "12345";

        String endpoint = "https://mychefserver";
        String client = "myuser";
        String validator = "chef-validator";
        String clientCredential = Files.toString(new File("C:\\Users\\myuser\\sandbox\\chef\\myuser.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8);
        String validatorCredential = Files.toString(new File("C:\\Users\\myuser\\sandbox\\chef\\chef-validator.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_NAME, validator);
        props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_CREDENTIAL, validatorCredential);
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_RELAX_HOSTNAME, "true");
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_TRUST_ALL_CERTS, "true");

        System.out.println("Setup complete.");

        ChefContext ctx = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("chef")
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .credentials(client, clientCredential)
            .overrides(props)
            .modules(ImmutableSet.of(new SshjSshClientModule())) //
            .buildView(ChefContext.class);
        ChefService chef = ctx.getChefService();

        List<String> runlist = new RunListBuilder().addRole("typicalapp").build();

        ArrayList<String> runList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String item : runlist) {
            runList2.add(item);
        }

        BootstrapConfig bootstrapConfig = BootstrapConfig.builder().runList(runList2).build();

        System.out.println("Configured the bootstrapper.");

        chef.updateBootstrapConfigForGroup("jclouds-chef", bootstrapConfig);
        Statement bootstrap = chef.createBootstrapScriptForGroup("jclouds-chef");
        SshClient.Factory sshFactory = ctx.unwrap().utils()
            .injector().getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<SshClient.Factory>() {}));
        SshClient ssh = sshFactory.create(HostAndPort.fromParts(vmIp, 22),
        LoginCredentials.builder().user(vmSshUsername).password(vmSshPassword).build());

        ssh.connect();

        System.out.println("Connected to SSH.");
        try {
            String rawScript = bootstrap.render(OsFamily.UNIX);
            System.out.println("Raw script rendered.");
            ExecResponse result = ssh.exec(rawScript);

            System.out.println("Bootstrap script executed...");
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + t.getMessage());
        } finally {
            ssh.disconnect();
            System.out.println("SSH closed.");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following output from SLF4J:

```
Setup complete.
Configured the bootstrapper.
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle registration succeeded
[main] WARN net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig - Disabling high-strength ciphers: cipher strengths apparently limited by JCE policy
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0_8_1_SNAPSHOT
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Server identity string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1
Connected to SSH.
Raw script rendered.
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.SessionChannel - Will request to exec `setupPublicCurl || exit 1
curl -q -s -S -L --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 600 --retry 20 -X GET  https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh |(bash)
mkdir -p /etc/chef
cat >> /etc/chef/client.rb <<-'END_OF_JCLOUDS_FILE'
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'ohai'
    o = Ohai::System.new
    o.all_plugins
    node_name "jclouds-chef-" + o[:ipaddress]
    log_level :info
    log_location STDOUT
    validation_client_name "chef-validator"
    chef_server_url "https://mychefserver"
END_OF_JCLOUDS_FILE
cat >> /etc/chef/validation.pem <<-'END_OF_JCLOUDS_FILE'
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    <omitted for security purposes>
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

END_OF_JCLOUDS_FILE
cat >> /etc/chef/first-boot.json <<-'END_OF_JCLOUDS_FILE'
    {"id":"jclouds-chef","run_list":["role[typical_app]"]}
END_OF_JCLOUDS_FILE
chef-client -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json
`
Bootstrap script executed...
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Disconnected - BY_APPLICATION
SSH closed.
And done!
```

When I SSH onto the server (`myapp01`), if I run `which ruby` I see that Ruby is installed. However `which chef-client` produces no output, and neither does `which java`. There is also no `/etc/chef` directory on the server. This makes me think that my code is only partially working, and perhaps only installing Ruby on the VM but nothing else. On top of this, unless I place a `System.exit(0)` after the "*And done!*" print statement, the code never exits. THis makes me think that there is a background/worker thread (maybe an SSH process doing something on the server) not returning/finishing.

There are no errors or exceptions that get thrown here.

My questions:

1. Can anyone see why this code isn't working (by "*working*", I mean, seems to only be partially installing Chef Client, and is not even installing Java, which is a part of the `typical_app` role)?
2. Am I missing anything in my code to prevent a background thread from finishing? Why does it never exit?

To reproduce, use the following Maven POM to pull down dependencies, and then run the code above, exactly as it is (just use your own Chef server and Linux VM).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <jclouds.version>1.7.3</jclouds.version>
    </properties>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>jclouds-sshj</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>chef</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Update:** here is my `/tmp/stderr` file I get after running @Ignasi Barrera's suggested changes:

```
--2014-07-22 10:58:14--  https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/13.04/x86_64/chef_11.12.8-2_amd64.deb
Resolving opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com (opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com)... 176.32.100.240
Connecting to opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com (opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com)|176.32.100.240|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 33399362 (32M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/install.sh.10185/chef_11.12.8-2_amd64.deb’

    0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  908K 36s
   50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1.13M 32s
  100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 26.9M 22s
  150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1.36M 22s
  200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 17.2M 18s
... omitted for brevity
32400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99% 2.64M 0s
32450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99% 26.2M 0s
32500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99% 31.9M 0s
32550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99% 6.12M 0s
32600K .......... ......                                     100% 4.09M=7.1s

2014-07-22 10:58:22 (4.49 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/install.sh.10185/chef_11.12.8-2_amd64.deb’ saved [33399362/33399362]
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it includes 3 different questions and does not provide a succinct explanation and reproduction steps.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree @sethvargo - I'll remove the 3rd bullet above, but if you read the entire question you'll see that the first 2 bullets are *very* closely related and can be answered by the same code change (the correct solution will allow Chef Client to properly install and the thread executing it will return). Also I could not provide a *more* succinct explanation and set of reproduction steps! Look above where I say, "*To reproduce...*", it doesn't look like you read that part. And in no way is this off-topic: this is a programming question that has no dupes and does show research.

Comment: My apologies. My previous answer in the related question was not 100% accurate and there were a couple manual steps needed to get the script properly rendered. I've explained them here and validated it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main challenge here is that you're trying to run a script on a node without using the jclouds compute service. The code uses jclouds-chef to generate a Statement, but that Statement is assumed to be executed by the jclouds compute service, which has its own mechanisms to render the scripts it executes.

In order to get the complete raw script and to be able to execute it directly using a raw SSH connection, a few things must be done manually. In particular, the jclouds-chef script assumes a few bash functions are defined, and those are missing when rendering the script this way.

You should change the creation of the `rawString` String as follows:

```java
StringBuilder rawScript = new StringBuilder();

Map<String, String> resolvedFunctions = ScriptBuilder.resolveFunctionDependenciesForStatements(
    new HashMap<String, String>(), ImmutableSet.of(bootstrap), OsFamily.UNIX);

ScriptBuilder.writeFunctions(resolvedFunctions, OsFamily.UNIX, rawScript);
rawScript.append(bootstrap.render(OsFamily.UNIX));

ssh.put("/tmp/chef-bootstrap.sh", rawScript.toString());
ExecResponse result = ssh.exec("bash /tmp/chef-bootstrap.sh");
```

This way the final script will have all the dependent functions. Also note that instead of directly running the script, I've changed the code to upload it, and then run the file locally. This will help you troubleshoot what is going on in case the script fails.

Also note that the script will generate the contents of the `/etc/chef` directory on each run, so before running it again you might need to delete that directory.

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi Barrera (+1) - **Please see my update (includes `/tmp/stderr`).** I made your suggested changes, and now the code does finish executing (no hung threads), however when I SSH into the machine it looks like the changes still didn't work. If I run `which ruby` I get `/usr/bin/ruby`, but `which chef-client` and `which java` (`typicalapp` is a Java web server) I get no output. There is no `/etc/chef` dir, and in the `/tmp` dir I see a `stderr` file whose contents don't actually contain any errors/exceptions. Any ideas/thoughts here? Thanks again!

Comment: After the failure, SSH into the machine, remove the `/etc/chef` directory if it exists, and run the script manually from there. You will see the output and what might be failing.

Comment: Thanks again @Ignasi Barrera, but I don't think you're understanding me: I'm saying that `/etc/chef` **never even gets created!** For example, after the code executes, I SSH into the machine and run `cd /etc/chef`. This produces output of `-bash: cd: /etc/chef: No such file or directory`.

Comment: The directory is created by the script, and perhaps it fails before. I'm just suggesting that you SSH the machine and run the script locally to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi Barrera (+1) - it looks like the `chef-bootstrap.sh` script itself is bad. When I run `sh chef-bootstrap.sh` I get the following error: `chef-bootstrap.sh: 5: chef-bootstrap.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. This corresponds to the following line of code: `function ensure_cmd_or_install_package_apt(){`. Any ideas?

Comment: Thw rendered script is bash, not sh. Are you running it with "bash scriptname"?

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi Barrera (+1) - yes I was executing the script incorrectly. After running it as `bash chef-bootstrap.sh`, I saw the errors: the `myadmin` user doesn't have `sudo` permissions and therefore when `chef-boostrap.sh` attempts to `mkdir /etc/chef` it doesn't have permission to do so. These VMs are provisioned through our VMware vCenter (using templates) and so I'm working with our Infrastructure team to modify the template and to give `myadmin` the right access it needs. Once I get to that point I'll try again and hopefully everything works!

Comment: And just to confirm, because this has been a fairly painful process (I'm sure for both of us!), the `chef-boostrap.sh` script should install **and run** the chef client on the VM, correct?  If not, what do I need to do to actually *run* Chef Client and configure the VM (as a `typicalapp` role)?

Comment: Yes, it will install everything needed and run Chef. Hope you get it working!

Comment: Took a while to get the request pushed through IT. **Yes, it works!** Thank you @Ignasi Barrera!